# Can a Flutter package only for phone, be used to a Windows app as well?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-desktop

I am building an Android Application with **Flutter & Dart** and i am using the "barcode_finder" package.[(https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_finder)](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_finder)

To be more precise, i want my app to **scan** a barcode.pdf (*barcode on top of a pdf file*) file and **extract** the info of the barcode.

When i am deploying the app on my phone, the application shows the (result) barcode info. But when i deploy it on my Windows computer, it can't find the result.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using does not have support for Windows applications.
Try out this dependency; https://pub.dev/packages/barcode

Comment: Thank you very much, but i am looking for a package that scans an existing barcode from a folder and returns its info. This package you send me is for generating a barcode.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to use that package on Windows as-is. It is a plugin package, which means that unlike most Flutter packages it contains native, platform-specific code for each platform it supports in addition to the cross-platform Dart code.

To make it usable on Windows, someone would have to add a Windows-specific implementation of that native code to the package.

Comment: Thank you, i found the package i need that is compatatible with Windows.